# node.js concurrent connection limit

Tags: node.js, performance, ubuntu, concurrency

I wrote trivial a `node.js` client/server pair to test local limits on concurrent connections. No data is sent between them: 10.000 clients connect, and wait.

Each time I run the test, I spawn a server and 10 clients that create 1000 connections each.

It takes a little over 2 seconds to reach ~8000 concurrent connections. Then it stops. No errors happen (`on 'error'` callbacks don't fire, `close` doesn't fire either). Connections "block", with no result or timeout.

I've already raised the max file descriptor limit (`ulimit -n`), and allowed more read/write memory to be consumed by the TCP stack via `sysctl` (`net.ipv4.tcp_rmem` and `wmem`).

What's the cap I'm hitting? How can I lift it?

-- EDIT --

Server program, with logging code stripped:

```
clients = []

server = net.createServer()

server.on 'connection', (socket) ->
    clients.push socket

server.listen 5050
```

Client (this runs `n` times):

```
sockets = []

for [1..num_sockets]
    socket = new net.Socket
    sockets.push socket
    socket.connect 5050
```

These are the system limits:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="500 65535"  
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle="1"               
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse="1"                 

sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem="4096 87380 16777216"   
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem="4096 16384 16777216"   

sysctl -w fs.file-max="655300"                      
sysctl -w fs.nr_open="3000000"                      

ulimit -n 2000000
```

Comment: What os you are using? Also if you can add your codes it would probably help to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem on Windows: 10k connections work just fine. Trying again with cygwin.

Comment: Could reproduce on cygwin. Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033631/node-js-maxing-out-at-1000-concurrent-connections - can you check out if those answers help!

Comment: @jsalonen the `posix` fix makes no difference. I didn't think it would, since I had set `nofile` (`hard` and `soft`) in `limits.conf` to a ridiculous number. Tried it anyway, but nope :(

Comment: Can you paste here what you get from `ulimit -n`? Also can you tell your node version.

Comment: Pasted all limits I'm aware of

Comment: Interesting. I got this to work in cygwin after calling `ulimit -n 10000`. Are you sure you are running the server with a user that has correct ulimit?

Comment: 100% sure, I even reinvoked `login` to get a fresh session after changing all the settings (so as to reflect changes in `/etc/security/limits.conf` as well)

Comment: If you only run 1 client with 10000 connections against the server does the error appear too? Or is it specific to running 10 clients with 1k connection each?

Comment: Fixed it. It was not a system issue: I limited the amount of simultaneous connecting sockets (not _connected_, _connecting_) to 10. As soon as a slot frees up, I start connecting another one. This fixes the issue. I'm sorry to have taken so much of your time