# Node JS application using 100% CPU

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

We are making a back-end application in Node.JS for an iPhone app.
We deployed our back-end application (Node) on EC2 instance (t2.medium) which is using MySQL server installed on another EC2 instance (t2.small). While doing load testing we saw CPU is using 100 %. We tried to find out reason but as far did not find it.

We are using following modules in our server.js.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var log = require('./utils/logger');
    var userRequestHandler = require("./requestHandlers/userRequestHandler");
    var authenticationHandler = require("./requestHandlers/authenticationHandler");
    var verificationHandler = require("./twilioVerification/verificationHandler");
    var eventRequestHandler = require("./requestHandlers/eventRequestHandler");
    var urls = require('config').get('urls');
    var sessionParameters = require('config').get('sessionParameters');
    var app = express();
```

We are using JMeter to do our load testing. With JMeter we could run 450 requests only (450 requests using single instance or 150 request with 3 instances). If we tried with more than 450, we got following error in JMeter.

```
   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
     at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:61)
     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
```

In case of 450 or less number of requests, our CPU usage reached 100%. We are new to Node JS, but as per our understanding our code is non-blocking but not sure though. Code of main method is given below, please let us know how to make it non-blocking if it is blocking code.

When we are calling first method, following code is being executed.

```
exports.authenticate = function(req, res) {
    log.debug(req.headers['deviceID'] + messages.enterMethod + new Date());
    var deviceId = req.headers['deviceID'];
    if(deviceId != undefined){
        log.debug(deviceId + messages.fetchFromDB + new Date());
        authentication.find({where: {deviceID: deviceId}}).success(function(authObj){
            log.debug(deviceId + messages.fetchedFromDB + new Date());
            var validationString = "<customData>";
            if(authObj != null){
                if(timeStamp > authObj.timeStamp){
                    log.debug(deviceId + messages.validateUser + new Date());
                    if(isValidUser(validationString, deviceId)){
                        log.debug(deviceId + messages.updateUserTime + new Date());
                        authObj.updateAttributes({timeStamp: timeStamp}).success(function() {
                            log.debug(deviceId + messages.updatedUserTime + new Date());
                                generateSession(deviceId, req, res);    
                        }).error(function(err){
                            res.status(500).json({status: err});
                        });
                    }else{
                        log.debug(deviceId + messages.InvalidUser + new Date());
                        res.status(401).json(messages.authenticationFailed);
                    }
                }else{
                    log.debug(deviceId + messages.wrongTime + new Date());
                    res.status(401).json(messages.authenticationFailed);
                }
            }else{
                log.debug(deviceId + messages.validateUser + new Date());
                if(isValidUser(validationString, deviceId)){
                    log.debug(deviceId + messages.createUserTime + new Date());
                    authentication.create({deviceID: deviceId, timeStamp: timeStamp}).success(function(authentication){
                        log.debug(deviceId + messages.createdUserTime + new Date());
                        generateSession(deviceId, req, res);
                    }).error(function(err){
                        res.status(500).json({status: err});
                    });;    
                }else{
                    log.debug(deviceId + messages.InvalidUser + new Date());
                    res.status(401).json(messages.authenticationFailed);
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        res.status(401).json(messages.authenticationFailed);
    }
};
```

Please help us to find out the reason of CPU 100% usage and how to test our application for 2000 or more users?

Let me know in case you need something else.

Regards,
Krishan

Comment: You are getting connection reset error because your server not able to handle load of 450 users parallel. Here no issue of Jmeter.

Comment: Not sure but this may be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033631/node-js-maxing-out-at-1000-concurrent-connections

Comment: Hi, please let me know if you still have the issue, I might be able to help. Let me know by replying to this comment.