# On AWS node socketcluster can't connect more than 1000 connections

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, connection

I am running a simple socketcluster node.js server and connecting to it from node.js websocket client.

By running the server on my local Ubuntu14.04, I could connect more than 10,000 clients to the server. But on AWS EC2 (c3-large) ubuntu14.04 instance the same code connects only less than 1000 connections.

Modified the etc/security/limits.conf and set the limits for "soft nofile" and "hard nofile" to 65535 on the EC2 instance.

Posix soft limit as suggested [Node.js maxing out at 1000 concurrent connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033631/node-js-maxing-out-at-1000-concurrent-connections) is not helping.

Other sysctl parameter doesn't differ much between my local ubuntu and EC2 instance.

Latency might not be an issue, because I tried to connect to server from multiple client machines still number of connection remain < 1000.

Is there any AWS environment variable that could effect the performance?
Is number of messages to and from EC2 could be a limitation?

```
var posix = require('posix');
posix.setrlimit('nofile', {soft:10000});

var SocketCluster = require('socketcluster').SocketCluster;
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var numWorkers = numCPUs;

var start = Date.now();
console.log("..... Starting Server....");

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log("***** SEVERE ERROR OCCURED!!! *****");
    console.log(err);
});

var socketCluster = new SocketCluster({
  balancers: 1,
  workers: numWorkers,
  stores: 1,
  port: 7000,
  appName: 'mysimapp',
  workerController: __dirname + '/sim_server.js',
  addressSocketLimit: 0,
  socketEventLimit: 100,
 rebootWorkerOnCrash: true,
 useSmartBalancing: true
});
```

--sim_server.js--

```
module.exports.run = function(worker) {
var posix = require('posix');
posix.setrlimit('nofile', {soft:10000});

var connection_db = {};
var opencount = 0;
var closecount = 0;
var msgcount = 0;

function status()
{
    console.log('open: ' + opencount);
    console.log('close: ' + closecount);
    //console.log('receive: ' + msgcount);
    setTimeout(function(){
      status();
    },10000);
}
status();

websocket_server = worker.getSCServer();

websocket_server.on('connection', function(socket){
    var mac;
    socket.on('mac-id', function(data) {
        opencount++;
        mac = data;
        connection_db[mac] = socket;
    });
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        msgcount++;
    });
    socket.on('close', function() {
        delete connection_db[mac];
        closecount++;
    });
});

process.once('SIGINT', function() {
    process.exit(0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad, there wasn't any issue in code or with AWS.
In my setup the switch/isp-connection that was used for AWS setup was not able to handle many connections.

Comment: So how many connections did you get in the end? Would be interesting to share some numbers (throughput, # connections) since socketcluster is relatively new compared to other websocket implementations and there is comparatively little data online about it.