# Websocket (node.js) connection limit, clients are getting disconnected after reaching 400-450 connections

Tags: node.js, performance, socket.io

I have a big problem with **socket.io connection limit**. If the number of connections is more than *400-450 connected clients* (by browsers) users are getting disconnected. I increased soft and hard limits for **tcp** but it didn't help me.
The problem is only for browsers. When I tried to connect by **socket-io-client module** from other **node.js** server I reached *5000 connected clients*.
Its very big problem for me and totally blocked me. Please help.

Update

I have tried with standard Websocket library (ws module with node.js) and problem was similar. I can reach only 456 connected clients.

Update 2

I devided connected clients between a few instances of server. Every group of clients were connecting by other port. Unfortunately this change didn't help me. Sum of connected users was the same like before.

**Solved (2018)**

There were not enough open ports for a Linux **user** which run the pm2 manager ("pm2" or "pm" username).

Comment: I had memory issues with socket.io with a simultaneous connections. Check if you have the same problems?

Comment: What kind of problems did you have? Did you resolve them? My version of socket.io is 1.3.6 but even the latest version 1.3.7 was this problem

Comment: Memory wasn't being released. I was using a lot of room and for some reason it was neither managing memory nor failing. Was noticing a lot of swapping.

Answer (score 3):

You may be hitting a limit in your operating system. There are security limits in the number of concurrent files open, take a look at this thread.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1393

Update:
I wanted to expand this answer because I was answering from mobile before. Each new connection that gets established is going to open a new file descriptor under your node process. Of course, each connection is going to use some portion of RAM. You would most likely run into the FD limit first before running out of RAM (but that depends on your server).

Check your FD limits: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/

And lastly, I suspect your single client concurrency was not using the correct flags to force new connections. If you want to test concurrent connections from one client, you need to set a flag on the webserver:

**var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {'force new connection': true});**

Comment: I have this limit and problem still exists.

*       soft    nofile  10240
*       hard    nofile  20480
root    soft    nofile  40960
root    hard    nofile  81920
www-data   soft    nofile  20480
www-data   hard    nofile  20480

Of course I used "{'force new connection': true}" attribute. Only then I could test many connections simultaneously.

Comment: What's the hardware specs?

Comment: I have Core i7 2c4t, 4GB RAM, 100GB SSD. The problem with losing connections occurs on other machine where is Intel 8c and 32GB RAM (production). Server can reach 500-800 connected users max. Does anybody have experience with traffic bigger than 1000 connected clients? I saw simulation where somebody achieved many thousands connections but I can't believe this was stable.

Comment: Lots of people get well over 1000 connected sockets, and unless you're sending massive amounts of messages a second it sounds like your hardware should support a lot. Can't really troubleshoot it much more without looking at the implementation

Comment: @PiotrChludziński I looked at this code a bunch of times, it's super simple, so it's not on the node.js side. Are you using Apache or NGINX over node, or just node directly? The fact that your other server increases the limit points to a configuration problem. Limits can be imposed along the process startup chain as well. For instance, are you using monit or Upstart? Upstart has it's own FD limit. Try setting a limit with posix http://stackoverflow.com/a/17033757/1056633

Comment: I use pm2 to run this server (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/). But even if I use server without pm2 problem still occurs. I connect to node.js directly from browser client.

Comment: I tried posix modul but it didn't help me. For real I can reach only ~250 connected users. I tried to add new users very slowly and limit is 250 not 500. Tcp connection number stuck on ~500 (2 connection for every client).

Comment: Ah, you should check with pm2 about settings. Your tcp_mem might be set for large bandwidth, increasing the memory usage per connection. Based on your app, bandwidth isn't a big issue

Comment: @Piotr Chludziński, did you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @AsishAP Yes I do. There were not enough open ports for linux user which started pm2 manager. ("pm2" or "pm" username)

Comment: @Piotr Chludzinski, please mark Christian comment about pm2 as the right answer.